# Definition of an ample sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-categories, derived-categories

I am reading the book “Fourier-Mukai transforms in algebraic geometry” by Daniel Huybrecht, on page 59, there is a definition for an “ample sequence” in an abelian category and another reference for this definition is the paper “Derived categories of coherent sheaves and equivalences between them” by Orlov. In the definition, it is written that the natural morphism $Hom(L_i,A)\otimes_k L_i \to A$ should be surjective. Here I have two questions. The first one is that where and how is this morphism defined since $A$ and $L_i$’s are objects of our $k$-linear abelian category and $Hom(L_i,A)$’s are $k$-vector spaces? And my second question is that why is this morphism natural?

Answer (score 2):

First, one considers the functor
$$
\Phi(-) = \mathrm{Hom}(L,-) \colon \mathcal{A} \to \mathrm{Vect}
$$
from your abelian category to vector spaces. Its left adjoint functor is
$$
\Phi^*(-) = (-) \otimes_k L \colon \mathrm{Vect} to \mathcal{A}.
$$
Now the morphism you are interested in is the counit of adjunction
$$
\Phi^* \circ \Phi \to \mathrm{id}.
$$
It is a morphism of functors, hence is natural.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May you also say a bit why has Hom functor a left adjoint?